# how to add PopupMenuButton inside card

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I have this card inside this card I need to add popupmenubutton. so I have tried adding but problem is that it's on the extreme left side which I wanted.

Updated :
I have tried this to add popupmenubutton but it's on the extreme left side which I wanted.

[image]

```
Card(
      elevation: 4,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 10),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 45,
                  height: 45,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage("Image here"),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50.5)),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                  child: Text("Name here"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: PopupMenuButton(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),
                    elevation:3.2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return [
                        PopupMenuItem(
                          child: Container(
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Text("Delete"),
                              onTap:()  {
                                print("deleted");
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ];
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, bottom: 10),
              child: Text("Date"),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(left: 75, right: 15),
                child: Text("Description"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

thanks

Comment: Share a code and some sketch what you want achieve

Comment: updated @LonelyWolf

Comment: good... now pleas make a sketch of desired result because I don't really understand your question

Comment: updated @LonelyWolf

Answer (score 1):

change this part of your code

```
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
              child: Text("Name here"),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: PopupMenuButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),
                elevation:3.2,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: Container(
                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Text("Delete"),
                          onTap:()  {
                            print("deleted");
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

with this one

```
           ...
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15),
                child: Text("Name here"),
              ),
            ),
            PopupMenuButton(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),
              elevation: 3.2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                return [
                  PopupMenuItem(
                    child: Container(
                      child: InkWell(
                        child: Text("Delete"),
                        onTap: () {
                          print("deleted");
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                 ...
```

In other word wrap your text with expanded and get rid of expanded from popupmenu

**Result**

[image]

Is this that you were asking?

Comment: I don't really get it. which part of the code did you change?